# Java: Error for no reason

Tags: java

**Hi**,
I need help in the field of validating data. For some reason i keep getting a incompatible error. I checked a couple times now that I have the right type. What is wrong, 2 classes. The error  is int the driver class keep bringing incompatibale tyoes in "name = student.setName( input);". Please explain why?

```
/*
* Joel Gordon
* per.4
*/
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class P5A
    {
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    student student = new student();

    String name, validate, valtests;
    int tests, score, count = 100;
    String input = reader.nextLine();

    System.out.println( "Please enter the students Name: " + input);
    name = student.setName( input);
    validate = student.validateData( name );

    System.out.print( "Please enter Test " + count + "(As number 1-3 for test number, then test           score):  ");
    tests = student.getScore( reader.nextInt(), reader.nextInt());
    valtests = student.validateTests(tests);

         System.out.println( stu.toString());



  }//end of main mthod
  }//end of main class/Driver
```

End of student Class driver.

```
public class student
{
private String name, result;
private int test1, test2, test3;

public student ()
{
    name = "";
    test1 = 0;
    test2 = 0;
    test3 = 0;
    result = "";
}//constructor

public void setName (String nm)
{
    name = nm;
}//setting the name in the program

 public String getName ()
{
    return name;
}//getting the name

public int getScore (int i, int score)
{
    if (i == 1) test1 = score;
    else if( i == 2)test2 = score;
    else test3 = score;

    if ( i == 1 )return test1;
    else if ( i == 2 ) return test2;
    else return test3;
}//getting score of tests

public int getAverage ()
{
    int average;
    average = (int) Math.round((test1 + test2 + test3)/ 3.0);
    return average;
}//getting a average of all the scores

public int getHighScore()
{
    int highscore;
    highscore = test1;
    if (test2 > highscore) highscore = test2;
    if  (test3 > highscore)highscore = test3;
    return highscore;
}//getting the highscores of all three

public String validateData(String name)
{

    if (name.equals("") ) result = "You have entered an invalid name, Please restart." ;

    return result;
}

public String validateTests ( int tests )
{
    if (test1 >= 0 && test1 <= 100 || test2 >= 0 && test2 <= 100 || test3 >= 0 && test3 <= 100)     result =  " You have entered an invalid number, between 1-100. " + 
    "Please restart!" ;
    return result;
}//getting the test scores and tesing each one against method

public String toString()
{
    String str;
    str = "Name: " + name + 
           "\nTest1:  " + test1 +
           "\nTest2:  " + test2 +
           "\nTest3:  " + test3 +
           "\nAverage: " + getAverage() + 
           "\nHighscore: " + getHighScore();
    return str;
}//putting all the tests together to view in termainal


}
```

Comment: You should read about `if-then-else` here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 1):

You are struggling with control flow.

What is happening is that when you call your `teacher` constructor, no matter what, the following lines of code are always executed:

```
    System.out.println ( "I don't have a teacher in that room." );
    System.out.println("Always show");
```

There are a few ways to fix this:

First, you can `return;` inside your `if` statements.

Or you can use `if` then `else if` then `else if` then `else` as the last one for each of your conditions.

Or you can use a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should make Teacher a class representing teacher. Then, you create instances of Teacher objects outside teacher class.

```
public class Teacher{
    private String name;
    private String catchPhrase;
    private int roomNumber;

    public(String name, String catchPhrase, int roomNumber){
       this.name = name;
       this.catchPhrase = catchPhrase;
       this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
    }

   //put setters and getters here...


   public String toString(){
     return "Name: "+this.getName()+"\nCatch Phrase: "+this.getCatchPhrase() + "\nRoom Number:   
            "+this.getRoomNumber();
   }

}
```

Then, you can create Teacher objects. For instance, you can put them in TeacherDriver class.

```
public class TeacherDriver{
    public static void main (String[] args){
    //create array of teachers (you can use list and other data structures if you want)
    Teacher[] myTeachers = new Teacher[]{
                                new Teacher("Mr. Clark", "Just do it", 225),
                               new Teacher("Mr. Harris", "Do the essays and you will pass.", 123)
                           };

     //ask for room number input here...

     //mark this truE if teacher is found
     boolean found = false;
     //search the array of teachers for a match
    for(Teacher chosenTeacher : myTeachers)
         //if the room number of the teacher matches your target room number
         //then display teacher info and stop reading the array
         //note: replace <your input room number> with your input variable name
         if(chosenTeacher.getRoomNumber() == <your input room number>){
            found = true;
            System.out.println(chosenTeacher.toString());
            break; //stop the loop

         }
    }

    if(!found){
         System.out.println ( "I don't have a teacher in that room." );
    }
}
```

A better way to do this though is to create another class that holds collection/array of Teacher objects.

Example:

```
public class TeacherList{
    List<Teacher> teachers;

    public TeacherList(){
          teachers = new ArrayList<>();

          //you can put initial entries like:
          teacher.add(new Teacher("Mr. Clark", "Just do it", 225));
          teacher.add( new Teacher("Mr. Harris", "Do the essays and you will pass.", 123));
    }

    public void add(Teacher e){
         teachers.add(e);
    }

    public void findTeacher(int roomNumber){
          //mark this tru if teacher is found
          boolean found = false;
          //search 
          for(Teacher chosenTeacher : teachers)
         //if the room number of the teacher matches your target room number
         //then display teacher info and stop reading the array
         //note: replace <your input room number> with your input variable name
            if(chosenTeacher.getRoomNumber() == <your input room number>){
               found = true;
               System.out.println(chosenTeacher.toString());
               break; //stop the loop

             }
          }

         if(!found){
             System.out.println ( "I don't have a teacher in that room." );
         }

      }

}
```

Then, in your main:

```
//create Teacher list
TeacherList myTeachers = new TeacherList();

//input room number here...

//replace <room number? with input variable name
myTeachers.findTeacher(<room number>);
```

If you want to accept multiple room numbers, then you can put the last two lines of codes above inside a loop.